# I bought a Velum without a hangar in GTA Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought a Velum without a hangar with hopes of using it for the Cayo Perico scoping setup. However, I didn't purchase a hangar before that because I am new to the game. I can't find the plane... do I need to buy a hangar, can it be spawned in, or am I able to refund the money?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand it seems you were able to purchase the plane, if that is the case if you call *Pegasus* on your phone and you should be able to spawn the plane at the nearest airfield. In terms of a "refund," there is no way to refund a plane.